# Unable to install TestNG plugin in eclipse manually

Tags: testng-eclipse

I am trying to install the TestNG plugin in eclipse it is not getting installed and i am getting the below error message

could not find "http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue. So, all you need to do is:

1. Click on Help->Install New Software
2. In the 'Work With' input box, enter this URL- https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site
3. Click on **Add** button
4. **TestNG** with a checkbox will appear below
5. Check that box and click on the **Next** button
6. Wait for the plugin to be downloaded

Welcome :)